# How would I pass a form value to a servlet

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, jsp, servlets

I am fairly new to programming so please bear with me .

I am trying to get values from a form ( in a JSP ) using javascript and do a post request to a servlet . My form has 6 values and I get the values in javascript using

```
var value 1 =    document.getElementByID(" value of a element in the form).value
var value 2 =    document.getElementByID(" value of a element in the form).value
etc
```

my question is I am using a POST request using the javascript Ajax call . How do I combine all these disparate values into a single element which I could then read and assign to a POJO using the POJO'S setter methods in the servlet . I cannot use a JSON because my project cannot use an external library such as Jersey. Any pointers to this would be appreciated .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are more elegant ways to do this, but this is the most basic.  You'll want to combine your javascript variables into a standard post body.

```
var postData = 'field1=' + value1;
postData += '&field2=' + value2;
postData += '&field3=' + value3;
/*  You're concatenating the field names with equals signs 
 *  and the corresponding values, with each key-value pair separated by an ampersand.
 */
```

If you're using the raw XMLHttpRequest facilities, this variable would be the argument to the `send` method.  If using jQuery, this would be your `data` element.

In your servlet, you get the values from the HttpServletRequest object provided by the container.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    MyObject pojo = new MyObject();
    pojo.setField1(request.getParameter("field1"));
    pojo.setField2(request.getParameter("field2"));
    pojo.setField3(request.getParameter("field3"));
    /*  Now your object contains the data from the ajax post.
     *  This assumes that all the fields of your Java class are Strings.
     *  If they aren't, you'll need to convert what you pass to the setter.
     */ 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response , what do I add to the datatype field  in the request

Comment: That depends on the type of response you're sending from the servlet.  By default it's text/html, so you only need to specify the dataType if you're sending back xml, json, plain text, etc.